# install apt-get on linux Red Hat server

Tags: linux, apt-get

I'm setting up a Linux Red Hat web server. apt-get isn't installed, but yum is. However, yum cannot find the apt package.

When I run apt-get, I get a message from the shell saying that the command apt-get couldn't be found. When I try yum install apt or yum install apt-get I get a message saying yum couldn't find the package and there was nothing to do

I suspect that it's probably a case of editing a sources list (as with apt) to add the source that apt is available from, but I a) don't know where this source list would be, and b) don't know what source would provide apt...

If anyone could enlighten me, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Cross-site related?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679874/318461)

Answer (score 10):

If you have a Red Hat server use *yum*. *apt-get* is only for Debian, Ubuntu and some other related linux.

Why would you want to use *apt-get* anyway? (It seems like you know what *yum* is.)

Comment: And remember, it's harder to use 'apt' as a verb ;) http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-1034.html

Comment: Re: Why would you want to use apt-get anyway? One of reasonable example is if you want to build a tool which operate on many different repositories (rpm, deb, etc) and you run something like `apt .. --download-only` on RH, to just collecting dependencies, and you work on files, not installing them.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on using `yum`, try `yum install apt`.
As read on this site:
[Link](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-apt-get-in-linux-instructions-installating-apt-redhat-fedora-t895.html)

Comment: Any enlightment on the downvote would be highly appreciated. I am just answering the question, rather than giving advice on sticking with yum?

Comment: Poster has already tried this and the information contained in the link is vague - do you really want to add repos to your sources without either a) disabling them and only using them on a case by case basis or b) only allowing them to update packages of interest

Comment: @ddawber Now I see, I've read the post 3-4 times and somehow I only picked up the `yum install apt-get`, and completely missed my proposal. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I guess I want to use apt as it's what I'm used to with ubuntu... I take it yum usage is pretty much the same?

Comment: @philip-mais: Not very acquainted with the program, but what I gather from [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) it looks pretty similar.

Comment: @Philip Mais Never try to use a different package manager than the default. Anyway, the commands you need are `yum install`, `yum update`, `yum remove` (use with caution), `yum history` (shows history of transactions), `yum history info` (shows what happened in a particular transaction), and `yum history undo` (undoes an entire transaction, ie undoing installing packages + their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into problems because RedHat uses RPM for managing packages. Debian based systems use DEBs, which are managed with tools like apt.

Answer (score -3):

> > wget http://dag.wieers.com/packages/apt/apt-0.5.15lorg3.1-4.el4.rf.i386.rpm
> >
> > rpm -ivh apt-0.5.15lorg3.1-4.el4.rf.i386.rpm
> >
> > wget http://dag.wieers.com/packages/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.3.4-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm
> >
> > rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.3.4-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm

maybe some URL is broken,please research it.
Enjoy~~

Comment: broken urls, and telling other to "research" doesn't add much